# Ajax Action Link CSS Class States

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Ajax.ActionLink in my ASP.NET MVC4 application:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Customer Activity" , "CustomerActivity",null, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "Button" })
```

I'm having an issue with the styling of this link. Currently it picks up the "Button" class, and and is styled correctly, but in my CSS I have a .button:hover and the action link ignores this completely. Does anyone know a way to prevent this?

Also, is there a way to set the above action link to inherit properties based on it's parents ID?

eg. The above link is in a list, but it completely ignores any styling that list has, and does it's own thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `a` with your selector and add `!important`

```
  a.button:hover{
   color:#ebe !important;
  }
```

Comment: you shouldn't need !important because a.button:hover should be more selective than just a:hover

Comment: @CSgoose, what will happen if you have `div a.button:hover` specified closer in the page

Comment: fair enough but then it seems like a developer problem because the stuff in the div a.button:hover you'd want to override the a.button:hover